# what dhikrs can i do in free time?

Tags: fiqh, dhikr

If this question seems silly i apologise but i don't have anyone to teach me really. What dhikrs can I do in free time?

Is like la illah ila allah x100 or more allowed? astagfirullah x100 or more etc or is this bidah? i don't want to be doing not allowed.

also can i pray nafls for no specific reason other than having free time? and as many as i like? i asked this yesterday but couldn't get an answer. i don't follow any particular madhab but i have been taught to pray hanafi when i was younger but say 'rabigfirli x2 in between 2 prostrations'

Comment: I'd suggest reflecting on verses of the Quran or learning Islamic knowledge if you have time. I don't know the authenticity, but my teacher once told us that learning one Islamic rule is more virtuous than a whole day of prayer.

Comment: I will do thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

As salaamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barkatahu,

In the name of Allah the most benificient and merciful.

You can do dhikr and azhkar as many times as you want there is nothing bidah in doing dhikr more than 100 times in any situation neither it's been said that doing dhikr more than 100 times is bidah. Also praying nafl prayers is good and you can pray as many nafl prayers as you like without any reasons the Prophet Muhammad peace and blessings be upon him used to prayer nafl prayers in the night which is known as tahajjud also other sahabs used to pray nafl prayers. There are certain times in which you cannot pray so you need to avoid those times and don't pray during those period.

As of saying rabigfirli twice between two prostrations I don't have knowledge of that.

And Allah knows the best. May Allah increase you and me in taqwa.

Comment: jazakallah brother !